# JQuery animation toggle change image

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle

I need help,
I created a script that hides / shows the menu and I added a image (icon/down.png).
I would like to change the image (down / up) when the movement changes.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function showDiv(element){
            $(element).animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 1000 });
        }
   </script>
        <img src="icon/down.png" width="12" height="12" /><a href="javascript:showDiv('#menu')">Menu</a>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Element A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Element A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Element A</a></li>
                   </ul>
```

Comment: Could you specify what part of your implementation isn't working? That'll make it easier to help you.

Comment: You might want to assign an ID to the img first, then use getElementById to fetch the image. JQuery would work too but it doesn't really make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/J8TfX/2/

```
function showDiv(element){
    var $img = $(element).stop().animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 1000 }).prevAll('img');
    if ($img.attr('src') == 'icon/down.png') {
        $img.attr('src', 'icon/up.png');
    } else {
       $img.attr('src', 'icon/down.png');
    }
}
```

Docs for `.prevAll()`: http://api.jquery.com/prevall/

Comment: I can save the status of the animation when the page changes?